# MySQL Different Result on WebService Call and WorkBench Call

Tags: mysql, workbench

I made a Stored Procedure.

When i tested it with workbench call, it worked well. but if i called that
inside webservice call, i got an 1217 result. (defined in procedure)

myTable is made with 3 column (user_no, index, count)
and this procedure is for subtracting multiple row's count.

```
DECLARE _affected_count INT DEFAULT 0;

IF ( o_ouput1 < i_input1 ) THEN
    SET o_result = 1211;
    LEAVE proc_body;
ELSEIF ( i_input1 > 0 ) THEN
    SET _affected_count = _affected_count + 1;
END IF;

IF ( o_ouput2 < i_input2 ) THEN
    SET o_result = 1212;
    LEAVE proc_body;
ELSEIF ( i_input2 > 0 ) THEN
    SET _affected_count = _affected_count + 1;
END IF;
```

// Same for input3~input6

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET count = CASE WHEN index = 1 AND i_input1 > 0 AND count >= i_input1 THEN count - i_input1
                     WHEN index = 2 AND i_input2 > 0 AND count >= i_input2 THEN count - i_input2
                     WHEN index = 3 AND i_input3 > 0 AND count >= i_input3 THEN count - i_input3 
                     WHEN index = 4 AND i_input4 > 0 AND count >= i_input4 THEN count - i_input4 
                     WHEN index = 5 AND i_input5 > 0 AND count >= i_input5 THEN count - i_input5
                     WHEN index = 6 AND i_input6 > 0 AND count >= i_input6 THEN count - i_input6
                     ELSE count END
    WHERE user_no = i_user_no AND index IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );
IF ( ROW_COUNT() <> _affected_count ) THEN 
    SET o_result = 1217;
    LEAVE proc_body;
END IF;
```

The Problem is.. If i call this procedure in workbench, it works well.

I can't understand why it's different when i called it with workbench and webmethod.

Is there anybody who can explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I Found An Answer

Use Affected Rows Option in on with Workbench, but not with webservice default.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count